# Feeding a macro with the expansion of an other defined "by" \csname

Tags: macros, expansion

I have a macro `\mymacro@i` that I want to "feed" with the expansion of another `\test`. With `\expandafter\mymacro@i\test`, it works.

Now, the `\test` macro can be defined by using `\csname`, say a `/test` macro. I can't find the combination of `\expandafter` to make it work the same way as with `\test`. How can I do?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\makeatletter
\expandafter\def\csname /test\endcsname{%
  \foo{bar}}
\def\mymacro#1{%
  \expandafter\mymacro@i\csname/#1\endcsname}
\def\mymacro@i\foo#1{%
  \def\temp{#1}%
  \show\temp}
\mymacro{test}
% Error: Use of \mymacro@i doesn't match its definition.
%
\def\test{\foo{bar}}
\def\mymacro#1{%
  \expandafter\mymacro@i\test}
\def\mymacro@i\foo#1{%
  \def\temp{#1}%
  \show\temp}
\mymacro{test}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to expand it twice now, once `\csname /#1\endcsname` to `\/#1` and the expand that macro. You need to add therefore *two* more `\expandafter`. The first one will expand the third `\expandafter` before the second, i.e. allows the third to expand the `\csname` construct, before the second one expands the resulting macro before `\mymacro@i`.

```
\def\mymacro#1{%
  \expandafter\expandafter
  \expandafter\mymacro@i\csname/#1\endcsname}
```

Comment: Thanks Martin! I'm quite sure I did try that. There must have been something wrong inside the csname that expanded to relax causing the mismatch definition.

Comment: I consider the construction with `\let` to be clearer. I think in this case it would be `\expandafter\let\expandafter\reserved@a\csname/#1\endcsname   \expandafter\mymacro@i\reserved@a` or something different. I always get very confused with nested `\expandaafter`'s.