# Is it possible to temporally make undefined \csname control sequence not silently expand to \relax?

Tags: macros

**Context**

Consider the following situation.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\makeatletter
\expandafter\def\csname/test\endcsname{%
  \foo{bar}}
\def\mymacro#1{%
  % Note the / *after* #1
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\mymacro@i\csname/#1/\endcsname}
\def\mymacro@i\foo#1{%
  \def\temp{#1}%
  \show\temp}
\mymacro{test}
% Error: Use of \mymacro@i doesn't match its definition.
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

I made a typo in the definition of `\mymacro` adding a `/` before `\endcsname`. The error shown made me believe that `/test` was improperly expanded by the three `\expandafter` but [I was wrong](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42423). As `/test/` is not defined, it silently expands to `\relax` and yes `TeX` is right saying that `Use of \mymacro@i doesn't match its definition` since I feed it with a `\relax` instead of a `\foo`.

**Question**

This behavior of `\csname` defined control sequence (that is expanding to `\relax` when undefined) is really handy but sometimes I'd like to deactivate it and maybe issue an `Undefined control sequence` error. Is it possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot alter the behaviour of `\csname`, but you can use e-TeX's `\ifcsname` to issue an error:

```
\csname
  \ifcsname#1\endcsname
  \else
    \expandafter\UndefinedName
  \fi
  #1%
\endcsname
```

where `\UndefinedName` is deliberately not defined. TeX will then issue an error complaining about `Undefined control sequence`, followed by `#1` (which is what you actually want to complain about).

(Unlike `\@ifundefined`, `\ifcsname` is expandable and does not add to the hash table.)

Comment: Thanks Joseph. That fits exactly my needs since i need it in an expandable context.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the command for existence and invoke the error yourself.

```
\@ifundefined{/#1/}{%
  \GenericError{}{%
    Command /#1/ undefined!
  }{%
    See the definition of \protect\mymacro!
  }
}{}%
```

The `\@ifundefined` macro uses `\csname` so it will define the macro as `\relax`. I don't think that this is an issue (we invoke the error anyways), but you can surround the code by `\begingroup ... \endgroup` to make the definition local.

Comment: LaTeX2e's `\@ifundefined` will leave the macro equal to `\relax` unless you use grouping, if it was previously undefined.

Comment: @JosephWright I know, but I don't think it is that an issue as we invoke the error message. However, I should have mentioned it, thanks!

Comment: Thanks. However I prefer Joseph's solution since it is expandable.

Answer (score 1):

In the question it is written:

*This behavior of \csname defined control sequence (that is expanding to \relax when undefined) is really handy but sometimes I'd like to deactivate it and maybe issue an Undefined control sequence error. Is it possible?*

`\csname` is used for obtaining a control sequence token from a sequence of tokens that at some stage of expansion yield a sequence of character tokens representing the name of the control sequence token in question. In case the control sequence token in question was undefined when applying `\csname`, it will get assigned the meaning of the `\relax`-primitive. (That assignment is restricted to the current scope even if the `\globaldefs`-parameter has a positive value.)

**Thus in this case, the `\csname`-defined control sequence does not get expanded to `\relax`. It does not get expanded at all as it is not expandable as it has the same meaning as the `\relax`-primitive which is not an expandable token.**

"Hitting" unexpandable tokens with `\expandafter` does not affect these tokens. `\expandafter` itself is expandable. All expansion takes place in TeX' mouth. Therefore processing `\expandafter` will take place in TeX' mouth. Unexpandable tokens are not affected by that. They reach the stomach of TeX.

`\mymacro@i` is expected to be delimited by the control word token `\foo` while the first `\expandafter`-chain from the expansion of `\mymacro{test}` "hits" `\csname` which in turn delivers the unexpandable control word token `\/test/` whose meaning equals the meaning of the unexpandable `\relax`-primitive. That unexpandable control word token is not affected when being "hit" by the second `\expandafter`-chain.

By the way 1: With delimited arguments usually the argument delimiting tokens get removed when TeX is gathering the arguments. Therefore in relation to gathering arguments, the meanings of argument delimiting tokens don't matter.  You can even happily use tokens that are undefined as argument delimiters.

By the way 2: Don't use the minimal class for minimal examples. Use the article class instead.
The minimal class was written by the developers of the LaTeX2e-package for testing the class loading mechanism of the LaTeX2e-package.