# \centering vs. centering environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lyx, ieeetran

According to
http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/IEEEtran/IEEEtran_HOWTO.pdf

It recommends:
Note that (1) figures should be centered via the LATEX `\centering` command—this is a better approach than using the `center` environment which adds unwanted vertical spacing;

But LyX will use `center` environment if you have a graphic in a figure and
choose center paragraph alignment.

You can, of course, just insert `\centering` with ERT.

Shouldn't LyX automatically use `\centering` as recommended when using
`IEEEtran`?

Answer (score 3):

The centering of content is generally considered an element that is independent of the document class in use, since you can still use the `center` environment if you want. Also, it is not specific to [`ieeetran`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ieeetran).

When I issue Edit > Paragraph Settings... > Alignment > Center for an image inside a figure, LyX places that image inside a `centering` environment, not the `center` environment. Yes, there's a difference.

[image]

Using the environment form of a macro (or switch, like `\centering`) is not problematic *per se*, since `\end{centering}` results in `\csname endcentering\endcsname` and even though it - `\endcentering` - doesn't exist, it doesn't generate an error (see section **11.6 Construction of control sequences**, p 116 of [TeX by Topic](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/texbytopic/TeXbyTopic.pdf)). Moreover, LyX ensures that `\centering` (albeit in its environment form) has an ending `\par`; necessary for setting the paragraph formatting.

The advantage of the environment form here is that the scope is limited to within the `\begin` ... `\end` clause.

Related:

- [When should we use `\begin{center}` instead of `\centering`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23650/5764)
- [What happens if you use a command form of an environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/311118/5764)
- [Is it possible to temporally make undefined `\csname` control sequence not silently expand to `\relax`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42465/5764)
- [Does the `\relax` side-effect of `\csname`...`\endcsname` still have a use?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66706/5764)